# How to show what is more $\sinh(2x)$ or $\frac{3^{2x}}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Which expression in more $\sinh(2x)$ or $\frac{3^{2x}}{2}$?

I try this

$$\sinh 2x = \frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2}$$

$$\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2} < \frac{3^{2x}}{2}$$

I has muliplay with 2

$$e^{2x}-e^{-2x} < 3^{2x}$$

Antilogarithms

$$2x \ln e - (- 2x \ln e)< 2x \ln 3$$

share by $2x$

$$\ln e + \ln e< \ln 3$$

$$2< \ln 3$$

Where I made a mistake? Thanks.

Comment: The mistahe is that $\log(a-b)\neq \log(a)-\log(b)$.

Comment: So is this correct $2x(\ln(e-e^{-1})) < 2x \ln 3$ => $e - e^{-1} < 3$

Comment: Try dividing by $e^{2x}$

Comment: Not more ! You are making the same mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x>0$

$$\frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2} < \frac{e^{2x}}{2}<\frac{3^{2x}}{2}$$

because $e<3$

For $x\le0$, $\sinh 2x\le0, 3^{2x}>0\implies$

$$ \frac{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}}{2} \le 0<\frac{3^{2x}}{2}$$